# Poisson process- Is this proof ok?

Tags: proof-verification, stochastic-processes, proof-writing, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I am writting the following proof and would like to know if you guys think it is good enough, or should I maybe explain it further. My concern is that I maybe should prove why the last claim I make (about the integral being different) is true.

Consider the generalization of the Poisson process with a time-dependant intensity of arrivals $\lambda_t$ such that $\lim_{T \to \infty}\int_{0}^T\lambda_tdt=\infty$. The time $t\geq 0$ at which the event occurs has c.d.f:
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P}(t\leq\tau|t>s)=1-e^{-\int_0^{\tau}\lambda_tdt}
\end{equation*}

*Claim:* in general, $\mathbb{P}(t\leq\tau|t>s)\neq\mathbb{P}(t\leq\tau-s)$

*Proof.*
Using the definition of conditional probability:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(t\leq\tau|t>s)&=\frac{\mathbb{P}(s<t\leq\tau)}{\mathbb{P}(s<t)}\\
&=\frac{\left(1-e^{-\int_0^{\tau}\lambda_tdt}\right)-\left(1-e^{-\int_0^{s}\lambda_tdt}\right)}{1-\left(1-e^{-\int_0^{s}\lambda_tdt}\right)}\\
&=1-e^{-\left(\int_0^{\tau}\lambda_tdt-\int_0^{s}\lambda_tdt\right)}\\
&\neq 1-e^{-\int_0^{\tau-s}\lambda_tdt}\\
&=\mathbb{P}(t\leq\tau-s)\\
\end{align*}
since, in general:
\begin{equation*}
{\int_0^{\tau}\lambda_tdt-\int_0^{s}\lambda_tdt}
\neq {\int_0^{\tau-s}\lambda_tdt}
\end{equation*}

if $\lambda_t$ is not a constant for all $t$.

Comment: What is $\tau$ here? Some kind of stopping time? Also by your notation, it appears as if $t$ is a random variable...

Comment: Yes! That's the CDF of $t$, I believe @GautamShenoy